# Where is Command Argument in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Where is Command Argument in Android Studio?? I need to set path of argc argv in jni to set debug path to my .cpp of android.

```
ShadowRemover::ShadowRemover(char* in) {
image = new Mat();
ReadImage(*image, in);
width = image->cols;
height = image->rows;
channels = image->channels();
```

This is my input path.

```
void ShadowRemover::RemoveShadow(char* out) {

// Set up data structures for each thread (openMP)
int threadCount = omp_get_max_threads();
Mat* blockList = new Mat[threadCount];
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
    blockList[i] = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC3, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0));
}
Mat dsMask = Mat(shadowMap->rows, shadowMap->cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

// Start clustering
```

This is my output path.

```
JNICALL
Java_com_example_admin_shadowdoctest_MainActivity_RemoveShadow(JNIEnv *env, 
jobject, int argc, char **argv[]) { 

// Check input
if (argc != 3) {
    cout << "Usage: DocumentShadowRemoval.exe InputLocation OutputLocation" << endl; 
    getchar();
    return -1;
}
// Remove shadow
ShadowRemover* sr = new ShadowRemover(argv[1]);
sr->RemoveShadow(argv[2]);
```

This is my main.

Comment: Which commandline arguments are you referring to? You don't start apps on Android devices from the commandline.

Comment: @Michael I mean input path of argument in commandline argument of debug like in visual studio because I create android ndk, and need to input path in debug. However, I find any solution to solve this.

Comment: I still find it unclear where you expect to get `argc` and `argv` from(?). If what you're really looking for are _compile-time_ "arguments" (i.e. defines), then you'd set those in your gradle script, or on the commandline if you're invoking `ndk-build` directly.

Comment: Okay I will try tonight and I will tell feedback. Ty to support.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, this works the other way around. Your app is Java, and the Java class **ShadowRemover** is a first-class citizen in your app. You can load *native libraries* from your app, and write part of your code in C or C++, but this is only relevant if you have cross-platform code that you don't want to rewrite in Java, or in the case of very specific performance-bound tasks.